# How to add ApplicationUser as test data in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to initialize some test data in my database, and having some problems adding password to the ApplicationUser in Identity Framework.

When I have done this earlier, I have used the seed method like this:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

    var adminuser = new ApplicationUser { Email = "admin@test.no", UserName = "admin@test.no", FirstName = "admin", LastName = "test" };
    userManager.Create(adminuser, "Password1.");
    userManager.AddToRole(adminuser.Id, role:"admin");
}
```

but as the seed method is not supported in dotnet core I have tried to add the dummy data in the following way:

```
using (var serviceScope = 
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

    db.AddRange(
        new ApplicationUser { UserName = "ola@nordmann.no", Email = "ola@nordmann.no" },
        new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test@test.no", Email = "test@test.no" }
    );
    db.SaveChanges();
```

I have also tried to use the same method I used in the seed method, but that doesn't work either as I get the following error message on the line were I add result1 to the database:

> cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Server.Models.ApplicationUser

```
using (var serviceScope = 
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var db = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var userManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    var au1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test@test.no", Email = "test@test.no" };
    var result1 = userManager.CreateAsync(au1, "Test123");
    db.Users.Add(result1);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql#seed-the-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else should be interested, I ended up with the following solution:

```
public async Task CreateUsersAndRoles(IServiceScope serviceScope)
{
    var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    await userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = "ola@nordmann.no", Email = "ola@nordmann.no"}, "Password1.");
}
```

and call on this method within the Configure method in the startup file like this:

```
await CreateUsersAndRoles(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PasswordHasher in combination with user.

i.e.

```
var user = new User(); 
var hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();

db.AddRange(
        new ApplicationUser { UserName = "ola@nordmann.no", Email = "ola@nordmann.no", PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(user, "Password1") },

    );
    db.SaveChanges();
```